# Friction causing an impulse

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

I have a quick question about impulse supplied by friction during a collision.  Given this situation:
[image]

The small bullet hits and sticks to the ball above the center of mass, causing rotation. 
If there is friction between the surface and mass M, will the change in momentum in the system on the horizontal axis before and after the bullet strikes the mass M, equal the impulse exerted by the friction force? Given there is friction, will it always exert an impulse during the ball and the M mass collision?

Comment: When you say *the system*, do you mean the bullet and the ball? Or just the ball? Also remember that $\mathbf F_\text{ext}=\dot{\mathbf P}_\text{COM}$

Comment: I forgot to mention it is a plastic collision, they are one body after the collision.

Comment: So by "the system" you mean the bullet and the ball together?

Answer (score 0):

> If there is friction between the surface and mass M, will the change in momentum in the system on the horizontal axis before and after the bullet strikes the mass M, equal the impulse exerted by the friction force?

We know that the rate of change in momentum of a system is determined by the net external force acting on that system.

$$\mathbf F_\text{ext}=\dot{\mathbf P}_\text{COM}$$
or
$$\Delta \mathbf P_\text{COM}=\int\mathbf F_\text{ext}\,\text dt$$

Since impulse $\mathbf J$ is defined as the change in momentum, we have
$$\mathbf J=\Delta \mathbf P_\text{COM}=\int\mathbf F_\text{ext}\,\text dt$$

If you take your system to be the bullet and the ball together, then the only net external force acting on the system arises due to friction (gravity and the normal force cancel out). Therefore, $\mathbf F_\text{ext}=\mathbf F_\text{fric}$. So that
$$\mathbf J=\Delta \mathbf P_\text{COM}=\int\mathbf F_\text{ext}\,\text dt=\int\mathbf F_\text{fric}\,\text dt=\mathbf J_\text{fric}$$

where $J_\text{fric}$ is the impulse caused by friction. Therefore, we see that the impulse applied by friction is in fact equal to the change in momentum of the system.

> Given there is friction, will it always exert an impulse during the ball and the M mass collision?

As long as 
$$\int\mathbf F_\text{fric}\,\text dt=\mathbf J_\text{fric}\neq0$$
during the collision, friction does supply an impulse to the system.

Comment: But in this problem it has to be ignored (for purposes of conservation of momentum before vs after the collision) because $dt$ is small and $F_{fric}$ is finite

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Why does linear momentum need to be conserved, exactly?

Comment: because the collision happens too fast for friction to change the momentum noticeably $\Delta P=F_{friction} dt$, it is infinitesimal

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Yes, if you want to assume the collision happens instantly then I agree. My answer doesn't say this isn't possible though. I try not to put in assumptions the OP doesn't make.

Comment: I agree with you, I just want the OP to be aware that he has to assume this in this kind of homework questions, unless given additional info

Comment: @Wolphramjonny I guess it depends on what the homework question actually is.